# Manually moving a Pioneer robot using P2OS

Tags: ros, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a Pioneer robot (P3DX) and when we send a Twist message with a forward movement to the base (/cmd_vel) but the robot doesn't start moving immediately. But if a rotation movement is sent (just rotation, no forward velocity), it does rotate immediately.

Is this a known behaviour of the P2OS stack? or the robot? or is this some kind of bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34679/manually-moving-a-pioneer-robot-using-p2os/) by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 408 on 2012-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-23**:
More likely some kind of configuration error.

**Comment by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on 2012-05-23**:
This is my configuration:

What configuration could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I forgot to put my findings. After a while I realised that the PID parameters where changed. I updated them and now the robot is response to moving commands is much more faster.

---

Originally posted by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) with karma: 408 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0